# Passing array of chars to a function by reference

Tags: c++, sql, arrays, pointers

I have a function:

```
 int getDBVal(UCHAR *myData[MAX_RECORDS], int &numRecords);
```

I call it:

```
int main()
{
    int rc;
    int NumRecords = 0;
    UCHAR *myData[MAX_RECORDS];

    rc = getDBVal(myData, numRecords)
    for (int i=0; i<numRecords; i++)
    {
       printf("Queue Name: %s\n", myData[i];
    }
}
```

The function fetches records from a database and is supposed to return them

```
{
  SQLFetch
  printf("Received %s\n", dataStruct[0].charCol);
  myData[y] = dataStruct[0].charCol);
  numRecords++;
  y++;
}
```

The output is:

```
Received queue1
Received queue2
Received queue3
Queue Name queue3
Queue Name queue3
Queue Name queue3
```

Why is the last response copied to all 3 of the calling programs array locations?

Answer (score 0):

```
dataStruct[0].charCol
```

It looks like you are setting the value from the index 0 for each one.  I don't know where dataStruct or where y are coming from since that code isn't posted though.

Comment: Sorry, I transcribed the code wrong, should say printf("Queue Name: %s\n", myData[i];

Comment: edited my answer, probably still need more info though.

Comment: I didn't want to put more code than necessary.  The fetch is in a do while loop the gets each row of data from the table, the contents of dataStruct[0].charCol always contain the data from that row.  You can see this in the printf("Received") immediatly following the Fetch.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that `dataStruct[]` is something that is overwritten on each call to fetch a new row. You are saving a pointer to `dataStruct[0].charCol` into each index of your `myData` array - not copying the text out of it. Since each `myData` entry has a pointer to the same location, you get the value that was last stored in that structure.

I would also make sure that `dataStruct[]` is not out of scope at the point you try to print things through the pointers stored in `myData` - that would invoke undefined behavior. But there's not really enough code here to guess at that...

Answer (score 0):

Variables `myData[y]` are all pointing to the address of `dataStruct[0].charCol`. To get the behavior you want, you need a deep copy. You will need to allocate enough memory at `myData[y]`, and copy the characters from where `dataStruct[0].charCol` is pointing to the newly allocated memory. You also need to remember to release the memory when you are done with it.

Just to make your life easier, use an array of `string`s: `std::vector<std::string> myData(MAX_RECORDS);`. You don't even need to specify the size of the array, as you can `push_back` and the vector will grow: `std::vector<std::string> myData;`.